# Laravel SelectRaw vs DB:Raw

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, sql-injection

**First:**

```
 DB::table('someTable')
->selectRaw('count(*), min(some_field) as someMin, max(another_field) as someMax')
->get();
```

**Second:**

```
DB::table('someTable')->select(
array(
        DB::raw('min(some_field) as someMin'),
        DB::raw('max(another_field) as someMax'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`')
    )
)->get()
```

> The above two query result is same , but my question is there any
>   possible security issues(SQL injections) with these two queries if i
>   use user inputs directly in where conditions.

Comment: Please provide an example

Answer (score 3):

As per Laravel's [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-methods):

> Note: The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding to protect
>   your application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to
>   clean strings being passed as bindings.

Comment: Yes that is correct but in DB::raw this text is "These expressions will be injected into the query as strings, so be careful not to create any SQL injection points!", So you need to careful how you use DB::raw, but in this case you have no input so no injection vector.